# dynamically run linux shell commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a command that should be executed by a shell script.

Actually the command does not matter the only thing that is important the further command execution and the right escaping of the critical parts.

The command that usually is executed normally in putty is something like this(maybe some additional flags for ls)

```
rm -r `ls /test/parse_first/ | awk '{print $2}' | grep trash`
```

but now I have a batch of such command so I would like to execute them in a loop

like

```
for i in {0..100}
 do
    str=str$i
    ${!str}
 done
```

where str is :

```
str0="rm -r `ls /test/parse_first/ | awk '{print $2}' | grep trash`"
str1="rm -r `ls /test/parse_second/ | awk '{print $2}' | grep trash`"
```

and that gives me a lot of headache cause the execution done by ${!str} brakes the quotations and inline shell between `...` marks

Comment: First, it's a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`. Can you describe the set of files that you want to delete? It looks like you are deleting files with the word `trash` in the file name.

Comment: I'm not sure why you refer to `$2` from the output of `ls`.

Comment: cause the output of ls has some rows with two columns where the second one holds the name and the first the timestamp as I said ls should have some flags

Comment: You should absolutely read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 aka "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"

Comment: Provide Short, Self Contained, Correct Example or keep whining on every answer that it is not what you are thinking. Your choice.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit because neither the question nor the discussion or the answers made much sense any longer. Feel free to clarify the question if you like, but don't remove the actual question and don't change things so much that the answers are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting this right is surprisingly tricky, but it can be done:

```
for i in $(seq 0 100)
do
  str=str$i
  eval "eval \"\$$str\""
done
```

Comment: Thank you actually only this solution fits my needs. Only minor modifications I made to my commands(I've escaped the ` and some $ to avoid the first eval).Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_rm() { rm -r `ls /test/$1 | awk ... | grep ... `; }
for i in `whatevr`; do
    my_rm $i
done;
```

Comment: No wrapping in a function is not an option cause the commands will be different. But thanks any way.

Comment: then fix your question. I bet you can still apply the principle of my answer.

Comment: yep there is a point in using function wrapping but for now I want to try with string evaluation cause it involves a smaller amount of efort to change the source

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
for i in {0..10}
do
    <whatevercommand>
done
```

Comment: looping is not a problem the Main thing is how to dynamically execute a command(by command i mean a long command with params inline shell executions and parameters like the ones in the post descrioption) that is stored in a variable

Comment: @JohnRobPeter Did you try my answer? I tested it with setup like yours (with `rm` changed to `touch`) and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually simpler to place them on arrays and use glob patterns:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

DIRS=("/test/parse_first/" "/test/parse_second/")

for D in "${DIRS[@]}"; do
    for T in "$D"/*trash*; do
        rm -r -- "$T"
    done
done
```

And if `rm` could accept multiple arguments, you don't need to have an extra loop:

```
for D in "${DIRS[@]}"; do
    rm -r -- "$D"/*trash*
done
```

UPDATE:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t COMMANDS <<'EOF'
rm -r `ls /test/parse_first/ | awk '{print $2}' | grep trash
rm -r `ls /test/parse_second/ | awk '{print $2}' | grep trash
EOF

for C in "${COMMANDS[@]}"; do
    eval "$C"
done
```

Or you could just read commands from another file:

```
readarray -t COMMANDS < somefile.txt
```

Comment: this approach is bounded to rm command but I need a more generic one that would execute any command given by a var

Comment: @JohnRobPeter Please see update. And that's the most generic form you can have. Commands can never really be stored on a variable and executed in a safe manner. At least in a truly generic way.

Comment: I wish you'd show how to change `awk '{print $2}' | grep trash` to `awk '$2 ~ /trash/ { print $2 }'`.

Comment: @tripleee That's not what he's really after actually. And parsing arguments through word splitting is never a safe way. That should have been obvious to you already.

Comment: Just a random [Useless Use of Grep](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) reaction.